# How to subtract objects with the same index from different lists that are within a two-dimensional array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I've already read some other Stack Overflow responses, but most of the ones I have seen so far are for Numpy or other languages.

This is the question that I am trying to solve: https://www.codechef.com/submit/SC31

I don't know the amount of lines that they will give me until I run it, so I can't just hardcode the amount of lists that I will need beforehand.

Here is what I am trying to do:
Let's say I had the two dimensional array:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I am trying to subtract the objects from the first list from the second list, and then the updated first list is subtracted by the third list.
The result that I am looking for is:

```
[-1, -2, -3, -4]
```

The objects from the first list index 0 is subtracted by the second list index 0 and so on. This is done for all the columns in the list.

Here is the code that I have so far but I am having trouble implementing the subtracting part.

```
for wow in range(0, int(input())):
    me_list = []
    thin = int(input())
    for thing in range(0, thin):
        temp = input().split()
        temp = list(map(int, temp))
        me_list.append(temp)
    good_list = []
    for number in range(0, thin):
        for speed in range(0, 10):
            me_list[number][speed] = me_list[number][speed] - me_list[number+1][speed]
    print(me_list)
```

I also can't print out the output of this code because it says the list index is out of range, not sure how to fix this because I thought that my for loops would stop iterating once the indexes would become out of range, but I guess that's not the case and I'm not sure what to change to fix this problem.

If you have any suggestions, I would appreciate it, thanks in advance.

Comment: so you cannot use any 3rd party library?

Comment: what's wrong with using `numpy` for such a task (`2*a[0] - a.sum(0)`)?

Comment: @PierreD Sorry, but could you explain why you multiplied it by 2? I checked the numpy.sum documentation and I think it would work, but I'm not sure why the two is there. Thank you.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your description of what you want to do.  I suspect that what you mean to say is that you want to subtract corresponding elements of the second and each subsequent list from the first list, so that the result is (*item_1_1* - *item_2_1* - ... - *item_n_1*, *item_1_2* - *item_2_2* - ... - *item_n_2*, ... *item_1_m* - *item2_m* - ... - *item_n_m*).  Have I gotten that right?

Comment: Also, I'm having trouble figuring out where the magic number 10 comes from.  And the codechef link does not help, because I don't see how that problem ("Weapon Value") is related to the task you present.

Comment: The wording is a bit confusing -- not sure I understood correctly. My understanding is "first row - second row - third row - ..." The sample data doesn't allow to disambiguate this understanding and another possible interpretation "second row - first row - third row", as in both cases the result is `[-1, -2, -3, -4]`. Anyway I posted an answer and please comment if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry about the unclear question, 10 is a number that is preset by the question. I've already solved the question so thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I commented in my answer, hope it would help you

```
rows = int(input("Input your number of rows: "))
columns = int(input("Input your number of columns: "))

result = [] # accumulately save subtracted list
for row_idx in range(0, rows): # loop over each row
    row = input().split(" ") # read data each rrow, each element in row is separated by one space
    if len(result) == 0: # check if the first row
        result = row # assign result to the first row
    else: # if result has data
        assert len(result) == len(row) # check if each row has same number of element
        result = [int(result[i]) - int(row[i]) for i in range(len(result))] # subtract the new input row to the accumulated result
print(result)
```

The input console

```
Input your number of rows: 3
Input your number of columns: 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

The result

```
[-1, -2, -3, -4]
```

Comment: The result `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is different from what the OP says they are looking for (`[-1, -2, -3, -4]`) in this case.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I followed the description he said and the output is that. Maybe the OP was wrong

Comment: More likely, you have misunderstood the OP's requirements (which would be understandable, as they are not expressed very clearly).  I take the expected result as pretty likely to be reliable.  Having discovered this discrepancy, this would be an issue to clarify via comments on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. This solution just performs the subtraction independently of the number of rows. I am hardcoding the lines but I think you were having problems only with the subtraction process. Let me know in the comments if you need help getting the input from the user.

```
test_data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [-4, -3, -2, -1]]

for i in range(1, len(test_data)):
    first_row = test_data[0]
    current_row = test_data[I]
    print(f"First Row {first_row}")
    for j in range(0, len(first_row)):
        first_row[j] -= current_row[j]

    print(f"First_row updated to {first_row}")
```

Result:

```
first_row [1, 2, 3, 4]
first_row updated to [0, 0, 0, 0]
first_row [0, 0, 0, 0]
first_row updated to [-1, -2, -3, -4]
first_row [-1, -2, -3, -4]
first_row updated to [3, 1, -1, -3]
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, if you are allowed to use `numpy`, I'd do:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4]])
res = 2 * a[0] - a.sum(axis=0)
>>> res
array([-1, -2, -3, -4])
```

Explanation:

"first row minus second row minus third row ..." is `a[0] - a[1] - a[2] - ...` which is `2 * a[0] - a.sum(axis=0)`.